# Mouse receiver shows up as keyboard too - is this an issue?

Tags: wireless, usb, badusb

I have recently seen some wireless mice that when the receiver is plugged in to a USB port, Windows device manager shows a new "HID-compliant mouse" (as expected) and also an "HID-compliant keyboard."  Is this standard practice, or should it raise concern?  Can something else be checked to see if there's an issue?
Is vigilance in Device Manager really needed?

Comment: You may look at Mousejack attack (https://www.bastille.net/research/vulnerabilities/mousejack/technical-details/). Also, there is a list of affected devices list you can compare with your mouse.

Comment: some mice have key macro capabilities, and some "press" special buttons, like the Windows button, for which they need a KB.

Comment: @dandavis Your answer-in-comments is the correct one and would have been marked Accepted as an Answer.  The mice prompting the question have forward/back Web navigation buttons.

Answer (score 1):

There is little need for concern here.  The wireless dongle you plugged in to your computer supports both a keyboard and a mouse, and is presenting itself as a composite USB device where both devices are attached.

The dongle can't tell if there is a wireless keyboard present, because battery-powered keyboards conserve battery life by not transmitting unless someone is pressing a key.  In order to avoid having the device driver enabled and disabled every time a key is pressed, the dongle simply says "keyboard is present".